# Extra hairline appears in UITableView Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom UITableView header using viewForHeaderInSection and the initial appearance looks great. However, when I scroll the header off screen and it comes back, there's an extra hairline separator at the top of my second section header.  I can also get it to appear when I swipe to delete the item immediately above the section header.  Of note, the top section header does not have this problem, only the 2nd section header and beyond.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { if (section == 0) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:248.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    UIView *topLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0.5)];
    UIView *bottomLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 38.5, tableView.frame.size.width, 0.5)];
    topLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [view addSubview:topLine];
    [view addSubview:bottomLine];

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: Can you show the immediate result without the hair line and the one with the unwanted hair line?

Comment: It won't let me post an image until I'm a more seasoned user, but here's a link to an external site with the image.  http://www.uidesignbyadam.com/new-page/

Comment: Right, post it somewhere else and post the link, as you did. Well, I would say that there is not an additional line. It is the same line in a different colour, some darker shade of grey. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Do your cells have a divider in them? You could be seeing an overlap of topLine in the header and the divider in the cell above it.

Comment: I was thinking that as well, except the cell dividers only come 80% of the way, there's white space on the left side you should notice no overlap with.  The extra thickness continues throughout the line, however, so I don't think it can be the cell dividers